# WPF command binding broken

Tags: c#, wpf

I saw this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070478/commandbinding-not-working) but when I tried it it does not work.

I know I can do mvvm but what the execute command be doing is view specific so I wanted it to be done on the view.

```
<Grid>
        <TextBox>
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Copy" CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, 
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
          AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}">
                        <MenuItem.CommandBindings>
                            <CommandBinding CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"
                                                Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"
                                                />
                        </MenuItem.CommandBindings>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = false;
        }
```

I am expecting the menu to be disabled but it is not:

[image]

I tried other approaches:

```
<!--Approach 2: CopyCommand as property of the Window. CopyCommand is in code-behind of the window-->
<MenuItem Header="_Copy" Command="{Binding Path=CopyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>

<!--Approach 3: Saw other samples on the net about binding to PlacementTarget. CopyCommand is in code-behind of the window-->
<MenuItem Header="_Copy" Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.CopyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
```

Comment: Where is your Command here ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan MenuItem.CommandBindings. See <MenuItem Header="_Copy" CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget,

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855188/wpf-command-binding-broken and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096186/why-its-not-good-to-expose-model-through-viewmodel-in-silverlight-mvvm/4154225#4154225

Comment: are you trying to implement wpf Application.Copy command??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my CopyCommand in the view's code behind.

View:

```
public ICommand CopyCommand { get { return _copyCommand; } }
```

Then I was able to access it when I put the view's instance in the textbox's tag property as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668654/relativesource-binding-from-a-tooltip-or-contextmenu)

```
<views:myView>

<Grid>
<TextBox Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:myView}}}">
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="_Copy" Command="{Binding CopyCommand}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
        </TextBox>
</views:myView>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement WPF inbuilt [ApplicationCommands.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) property all you need to do is

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

Since the command is associated with the textbox it will automatically handle the execute and can execute events.

However if you want to implement your own custom command you have to be little bit verbose

```
public static class MyCommands
{
    public static readonly RoutedUICommand Copy= new RoutedUICommand
            (
                    "Copy",
                    "_Copy",
                    typeof(MyCommands),
                   null
            );

    //You can define more commands here
}

private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender,  CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        e.CanExecute = true; //can check with debugger...
}

private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //Your Action   
}
```

in your xaml

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:MyCommands.Copy" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Grid>

    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="local:MyCommands.Copy"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

Specify `Command` in your `MenuItem` like this :

```
<MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" .../>
```

Also specify a value for `Command` property in the `CommandBinding`,

```
<MenuItem.CommandBindings>
     <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"
                     Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
</MenuItem.CommandBindings>
```

Comment: I tried <CommandBinding CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"
                                                Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"
                                            Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"/> but it did not work. I looked at Snoop and it contains the command property however the events as well as the Command is not being called. I'm going crazy over this issue.